# show something when listview is empty

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview that shows up when a fragment is opened being updated by a saved list. Initially that list is empty so it spits out an error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0. So i want to show show something like a text saying something like empty so that when there is something in the list it will display. I have tried using the getEmptyView but to no avail. Can i please get some help on how to accomplish this thank you.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reading_monday, container, false);

    addNewButton = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewReadingMonday);
    relativeLayoutMonday = (RelativeLayout) customView.findViewById(R.id.frameLayoutMonday);
    listViewMonday = (ListView)customView.findViewById(R.id.listViewMonday);
    listContainerMonday = (RelativeLayout)customView.findViewById(R.id.listContainerMonday);
    tinyDB = new TinyDB(getContext());
    addNewSubject = (Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddNewSubjectMonday);
    dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayListSubjectsRead = new ArrayList<>();
    timeOne = new ArrayList<>();
    timeTwo = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new CustomListAdapterReading(getContext(), dataModels);

        TextView empty = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.emptyTextView);
        listViewMonday.setEmptyView(empty);


            arrayListSubjectsRead =  tinyDB.getListString("ArrayForSubjects");
            timeOne = tinyDB.getListString("ArrayForTimeOne");
            timeTwo = tinyDB.getListString("ArrayForTimeTwo");

            dataModels.add(new DataModelReading(arrayListSubjectsRead, timeOne, timeTwo));

            adapter = new CustomListAdapterReading(getContext(), dataModels);
            listViewMonday.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            System.out.println(" subjects: "+arrayListSubjectsRead);
            System.out.println("timeone: "+ timeOne);
            System.out.println("timetwo: "+timeTwo);









    addNewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            relativeLayoutMonday.removeView(noEventTextView);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ReadMain.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    addNewSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });




    return customView;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017088/android-displaying-text-when-listview-is-empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want you to check this post [setEmptyView on ListView not showing its view in a android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483508/setemptyview-on-listview-not-showing-its-view-in-a-android-app), it should solve your empty view issue.
And if you want to prevent the app from throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException, you can simply check the size of your `dataModels` array before setting up your adapter.

```
if (dataModels.size() > 0)
{
    //Setup our adapter here
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
ImageListAdapter imageListAdapter= new ImageListAdapter();
listviewObject.setAdapter(imageListAdapter);

if (imageListAdapter!= null)
    if (imageListAdapter.getCount() > 0){
        // implement your work
    }else {
        // do whatever you want on empty list adapter 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this way in my application

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.listView);
TextView noData = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.noData);
listView.setEmptyView(noData);
```

Listview will automatically set no data text when adapter is empty.